# Compositional inverse of a power series

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics

If \$f(x) = x + \sum_{i>1} a_ix^i\$ and \$g(x)=x+\sum_{i>1}b_ix^i\$ then there is a composite power series \$f(g(x))\$ also of this form. Given a power series \$f\$ the goal is to find a compositional inverse \$f^{-1}\$ so that \$f(f^{-1}(x))=x\$.

One approach to this is recursive: start with a guess \$g_1(x)=x\$ for the inverse. Suppose that \$f(g_{n-1}(x))=x+c_{n}x^n + O(x^{n+1})\$. Then set \$g_n(x)=g_{n-1}(x)-c_nx^n\$. Then \$f^{-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n\$. (The sequence \$g_n\$ is convergent in the power series norm so this limit is well defined.)

A second approach is to use the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem), which says that \$f^{-1}(x)=\sum b_ix^i\$ where

\$\displaystyle \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\,\,\,\,\,\,\, b_i=\frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{w}{f(w)}\right)^n\$.

### Task

Input: A list of integers \$[a_2, a_3,..., a_n]\$

Output: A list of integers \$[b_2,\ldots, b_n]\$ such that if

\$\displaystyle \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad f(x)=x+\sum_{i=2}^n a_ix^i\$

and

\$\displaystyle \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad g(x)=x+\sum_{i=2}^n b_ix^i\$

then

\$\displaystyle \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \,\,\,\,f(g(x))=x+O(x^{n+1})\$

You may alternatively accept input in whatever other format is most convenient. If you wish to accept an input list padded like \$[0, 1, a_2,\ldots,a_n]\$ or like \$[1,a_2,\ldots, a_n]\$ that is acceptable. If you wish to pad the output in either of these ways that is acceptable too.

### Scoring

This is code golf so shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] => [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] => [-1, 0, 2, -2, -5, 14, 5, -72, 68, 
  278]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] => [-2, 5, -14, 42, -132, 429, -1430, 4862, -16796, 58797]
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36] => [-1, -2, 6, 16, -67, -164]
[0, 0, 2, -4, 2, 3] => [0, 0, -2, 4, -2, 13]
[1, 2, -5, 1, 4, -5] => [-1, 0, 10, -47, 87, 333]
[2, 1, 0, 4, -3, -1] => [-2, 7, -30, 139, -669, 3285]
```